# Getting Started with Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: python, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I decided to learn to develop Firefox add-ons using the Add-on SDK and I was following the [tutorial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/getting-started-with-cfx.html) from the Mozilla website. When I got to the point of running `cfx run` I got the following exception *(What the heck)*:

**NOTE:** Firefox version 23.0, Add-on SDK 1.14, Python 2.6.6, OS Windows XP SP3

```
(D:\addon-sdk-1.14) D:\my_addon>cfx run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\addon-sdk-1.14\bin\cfx", line 33, in <module>
    cuddlefish.run()
  File "D:\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\__init__.py", line 928, in run
    bundle_sdk=options.bundle_sdk)
  File "D:\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\runner.py", line 640, in run_app

    print >>sys.stderr, "Using binary at '%s'." % runner.binary
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp720
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python26\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "D:\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\runner.py", line 534, in maybe_r
emove_outfile
    os.remove(outfile)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process: 'c:\\docume~1\\ab\\locals~1\\temp\\harness-stdout-p7spr
q'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python26\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "D:\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\runner.py", line 534, in maybe_r
emove_outfile
    os.remove(outfile)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process: 'c:\\docume~1\\ab\\locals~1\\temp\\harness-stdout-p7spr
q'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's a python (2.6) bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671522)

Try the proposed workaround or upgrade to 2.7

Comment: Thank you very much, I Googled but couldn't find anything. Upgrading to `Python 2.7.5` solved my problem.

Comment: -argh, it is impossible to delete this-

Comment: Installed Python 2.7.6 and had the error, downgraded to 2.6.6 and fixed it :)

Comment: @paa can you help me on this topic sir? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139984/firefox-getting-started-with-nodejs-and-jpm

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention, using Python 2.7 might not work for some people. The Add-On SDK's `README` file states "Before proceeding, please make sure you've installed Python 2.5, 2.6, or 2.7", so I originally installed Python 2.7.6. (Note that this is with version 1.15 of the Add-On SDK.) Upon entering `cfx run`, I got a similar (though not identical) error message (which can be found [in my bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=958609)). After downgrading to Python 2.6.6, I no longer receive that error. Indeed, [the Troubleshooting page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Troubleshooting) for the Add-On SDK states that `cfx currently expects Python 2.5 or 2.6. Older and newer versions may or may not work.`